# Euler characteristics of Tensor power of line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety,
and $L$ a line bundle on $X$ which satisfies $L^{\otimes n}=O_X$ for some $n$. I am wondering whether there is a relation between $\chi(L)$ and $\chi(O_X)$. Something like $\chi(L)=\chi(O_X)^n$ seems too optimistic.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head, but I would imagine that you should adjust the formula. Since $L^{\otimes kn}=\mathcal{O}_X$ as well, the formula should be correct in this case too, and it's clear that what you have wouldn't work unless $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L^{\otimes n} \cong O_X$ then $L$ is numerically trivial, i.e., $c_1(L) = 0$ in $CH^1(X)_{num}$. Therefore, by Riemann--Roch 
$$
\chi(L) = \chi(O_X).
$$

Comment: great, many thanks!